# using xml type attribute for derived complex types

Tags: xml, schema

I'm trying to get derived complex types from a base type in an xsd schema.

it works well when I do this (inspired by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256157.aspx)):

xml file:

```
     <person
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="Employee">
        <name>John</name>
        <height>59</height>
        <jobDescription>manager</jobDescription>
     </person>
```

xsd file:

```
     <xs:element name="person" type="Person"/>

         <xs:complexType name="Person" abstract="true">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name= "name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name= "height" type="xs:double" />
         </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>

         <xs:complexType name="Employee">
         <xs:complexContent>
             <xs:extension base="Person">
                <xs:sequence>
                   <xs:element name="jobDescription" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
         </xs:complexType>
```

However, if I want to have the person element inside, for example, a sequence of another complex type, it doesn't work anymore:

xml:

```
    <staffRecord>
      <company>mycompany</company>
      <dpt>sales</dpt>
      <person
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="Employee">
        <name>John</name>
        <height>59</height>
        <jobDescription>manager</jobDescription>
      </person>
    </staffRecord>
```

xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="staffRecord">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="company" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="dpt" type="xs:string"/>

        <xs:element name="person" type="Person"/>

            <xs:complexType name="Person" abstract="true">
             <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name= "height" type="xs:double" />
             </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="Employee">
             <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="Person">
                   <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="jobDescription" type="xs:string" />
                   </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:extension>
             </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>


    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When validating the xml with that schema with xmllint (under linux), I get this error message then:

> config.xsd:12: element complexType:
>   Schemas parser error : Element
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}sequence':
>   The content is not valid. Expected is
>   (annotation?, (element | group |
>   choice | sequence | any)*). WXS schema
>   config.xsd failed to compile

Any idea what is wrong ?

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root element of your XML file should have all complex types defined in the namespace.

http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter13.html

Comment: There is no need to separate the definition of types from the definition of elements.  If a given type is only used in one element, then it can just be defined within that element.

Answer (score 0):

xsd:sequence elements can only contain one of the following list of child elements:
at most one *annotation*, and as many of *element, group,  choice,  sequence, any*, as you desire.

Your sequence element has two complexType elements in it, which is invalid.

EDIT: 
See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-sequence for details.

EDIT 2:
A `sequence` is a sequence of *elements*, not of *types*.  There is no polymorphism. It is not good enough to state that an element X contains the sequence A,B, and anything that looks a bit like a C, you must state exactly which C-like element you want.

Your options include,

a) Define `element` elements that correspond to the Person and Employee types at the root level (i.e. under xs:schema), and refer to them under *staffRecord* with `element[@ref]`

b) wrap the two `complexType` elements in two separate `element` elements.

Comment: yeah, well I can read the error message... that doesn't help in solving the problem though

Comment: You asked what was wrong, my answer was complete.  It does help solve the problem, all you have to do is choose an element from the list of allowable elements, and use that instead.

I have now updated my answer to give two potential solutions.

Comment: so, if someone posts something like "I get a 'compilation error', what's wrong?", you are going to reply "it happens because you compiler encountered an error"... very useful

Comment: That depends. With that exact question, then yes.  With a question like yours, I will (as I did for you) attempt to help you interpret that error message, as it looked like you had trouble understanding it.

This is a Question and Answer site, you ask questions and get answers to those questions.  If you want an answer to a different question, ask that question instead.